# Load CSS before Theme CSS

Tags: plugins, functions, css, wp-enqueue-style

I have a stylesheet I want to load first in the head before other plugins load css or theme css. For some reason priority is not working for me. Any idea how I can achieve this? I need to use functions as this stylesheet only loads on a specific page

Comment: the code you're using to do this is missing, can you edit your question to include it?